# How can I mock a service that gets immediately invoked when the controller loads?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a controller that immediately grabs some data from a service when it loads.

```
angular.module('app').controller("MyController", function (myService) {
    var projectId = myservice.project.id;
});
```

This data gets set from a previous action in the application. So when karma/jasmine loads this controller in a fresh state this service doesn't have this data. I've tried mocking this service in a beforeEach block but haven't had any luck.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    var myService = {
        project: {
            id: 'thadsfkasj'
        }
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock your service using `angular.value`. This should allow you to then inject `myService` into your controller.

```
angular.module('myServiceMock', [])
    .value('myService',
    {
        project: {
            id: 'thadsfkasj'
        }
    });

beforeEach(module(
    'myServiceMock'
    //other modules or mocks to include...
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ngMock as well?

If so, you should do the following:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    var myService = {
        project: {
            id: 'thadsfkasj'
        }
    }
    $provide.value('myService', myService);
}));
```

[Test AngularJS factory function with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15926336/1130374)

Answer (score 0):

Without having to deal with injecting $provide or overriding modules, you can simply pass in an object representing your mock when you instantiate your controller in your tests.

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
  myMockService = {
    project: {
      id: 100
    }
  };

  ctrl = _$controller_('MyController', {
    ...
    myService: myMockService
    ...
  });
}));
```